# Given a triangle ABC and a new angle $\angle ABC$ how do you find the new position of B given that B only moves in the X direction?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have a triangle ABC of which I know all positions, now I want to set angle $\angle ABC$ to a certain angle by only moving point B in the x direction. How do I figure out the new location of B'. Triangle ABC is random and B can also not lie on the X axis. Can someone help me figure this out? The only similar question that I found is here: [Given triangle ABC, how to move point B to a certain angle given that its new location lies within the direction of its old altitude.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610286/given-triangle-abc-how-to-move-point-b-to-a-certain-angle-given-that-its-new-lo) But the solution is not that clear to me.

Comment: That could be impossible for some values of the angle and positions of $B$.

Comment: I am aware, but I am interested in what the answer is when it is possible.

Comment: Construct over $AC$ those two circular arcs whose points see $AC$ under the given angle. Construct a line through $B$ parallel to $x$-axis. The intersections between this line and the arcs give the possible locations of $B'$.

Comment: Here's the construction for you to explore: https://www.geogebra.org/m/zquc5qge

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks a lot this solution seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

The algebra behind this is as follows: The points $\vec A$, $\vec B$ and
$\vec C$ are the corners of the triangle and have known coordinates.
In addition a vector $\vec x$ is known which provides the direction
on which $\vec B$ is allowed to move. The new point $\vec B'=\vec B+t\vec x$
is parameterized as a shifted $\vec B$ and the task is to find the
scalar multiplier $t$. The condition is that the direction from $\vec A$
to $\vec B'$ and the direction from $\vec C$ to $\vec B'$ build a known angle
$\alpha$. The cosine of the angle is the normalized
dot product between direction, and the directions are differences
between the coordinate vectors, $\vec C-\vec B'$ and $\vec A-\vec B'$.
$$
(\vec C-\vec B-t\vec x)\cdot
(\vec A-\vec B-t\vec x)=\cos\alpha |\vec C-\vec B-t\vec x|\,|\vec A-\vec B-t\vec x|
;
$$
$$
x^2 t^2 -\vec x\cdot (\vec C+2\vec B-\vec A)t+(\vec C-\vec B)\cdot(\vec A-\vec B)
$$
$$
=\cos\alpha \sqrt{x^2 t^2+(\vec C-\vec B)^2-t\vec x\cdot(\vec C-\vec B)}
\sqrt{x^2t^2-t\vec x(\vec A-\vec B)+(\vec A-\vec B)^2}
$$
where $x^2=\vec x\cdot \vec x$.
Squaring both sides gives a polymomial of 4th degree in $t$. The solution
is to find the real-valued root(s) of this polynomial, and to compute
$\vec B'=\vec B+t \vec x$.

Comment: I get the following terms: $$x^4 $$ $$x^3 \cdot  (2(\vec C+2\vec B-\vec A)-\cos\alpha^2((\vec C-\vec B)+(\vec A- \vec B))) $$ $$x^2 \cdot (((\vec C+2\vec B-\vec A)^2 + 2(\vec C-\vec B) \cdot (\vec A- \vec B)) - \cos\alpha^2((\vec C-\vec B)^2+(\vec A -\vec B)^2)+ (\vec C-\vec B) \cdot (\vec A -\vec B))$$ $$ \vec x \cdot (-2(\vec C+2\vec B-\vec A) \cdot ((\vec C-\vec B)\cdot(\vec A-\vec B)) + \cos\alpha^2((\vec C - \vec B)^3 + (\vec A - \vec B)^3))$$ $$ (\vec C - \vec B) \cdot (\vec A - \vec B) - \cos\alpha^2((\vec C - \vec B)^2 \cdot (\vec A - \vec B)^2) $$ This isnt correct where do I go wrong

Comment: After the squaring the left hand sides has a contribution $x^4t^4$ and the
right hand side a contribution $\cos^2\alpha x^4t^4$, so obviously the
coefficient of $[t^4]$ of the polynomial is $x^4\sin^2\alpha$. Where did you lose the $\alpha$?